# change state of button with document.getElementById("id").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that display a certain text at first, but when i click it i would like it to display something else.

Here is the html input:

```
<label class="button">
<input type="checkbox" id="control" onchange="changeState();">
<span class="button1" style="color: #4CAF50">Pull</span>
</label>
```

and here is my function:

```
function changeState() {
  if (active == false) {
    active = true;
    start_timer();
    var myStop = "Stop"
    document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = myStop.fontcolor("#f00");
  } else {
    active = false;
    var myPull = "Pull"
    document.getElementById("control").innerHTML = myPull.fontcolor("#4CAF50");
  }
}
```

When i used `<button></button>` instead of `<input>` it used to work but i need to use the input for something else. any idea what i would have to change to get it to work? I'm really new to HTML and JavaScript so I'm sort of clueless right now.

Comment: An `<input>` can have no child elements, therefore it has no `innerHTML` to change, therefore using `innerHTML` to update the content cannot work. Instead, use `value`, or use the `<button>` as you did previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the input is just a checkbox. As mentioned, there's no innerHTML.  It's the span you want to change.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button1')

function changeState() { 
  let checked = document.getElementById('control').checked
  if (checked) {  
     let myStop = "Stop"
     button.innerText = myStop;
     button.style.color='red'
  }else{
     let myPull = "Pull"
     button.innerText = myPull;
     button.style.color="#4CAF50";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="button">
   <input type="checkbox" id="control" onchange="changeState();">
   <span id="button1" style="color: #4CAF50">Pull</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Alright its working, the only thing is that the function ```start_timer()``` is not working when inserted in the ```if (checked)```

Comment: update your question and supply start_timer() function

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without the span:

```js
function changeState(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.color = "#f00"
    e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = "Stop"
  } else {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.color = "#4CAF50"
    e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = "Pull"
  }
}

document.querySelector("#control").onchange = changeState;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="control" name="control">

<label for="control" class="button" style="color: #4CAF50">
Pull
</label>
```

You may want to go further and use a class and `classList.toggle()` to handle the fontcolor.